# Permission denied error in all.js

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using all.js for facebook implementation. I used a facebook button on signup page . by logging through  facebook i am getting user name and email of facebook user into the fields on sign up page. 
It's working fine on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but its giving error on IE8.

the error is in all.js line 22

```
{FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id]=b;if(a.params)b.fbCallID=a.id;
```

Please help me if any one knows why this problem is occuring .

Thanks
Udham

Comment: Tons of similar questions: [1](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7343226/facebook-login-throws-permission-denied), [2](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7346333/permission-denied-error-in-all-js), [3](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6678376/facebook-connect-cant-login-in-using-ie-permission-denied), [4](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6654892/facebook-connect-access-denied-on-line-22-all-js-in-ie7-8) — I've voted to close the others in an attempt to make this one the canonical question.

Comment: @apaidnerd From what I can tell... there are several reasons why you might get a permission denied error in the all.js file -- voting to close all but one is like voting to close all C questions that include a buffer overflow - the permission denied error is a symptom... not the actual bug

Comment: @Jiaaro - Your analogy is incorrect. The ones I voted on are related to one particular Facebook bug.

Answer (score 10):

Try this out. It worked for me, may help some one.

```
FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b){FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; }
```

Ideally attach debugger and see which method breaks up and hack it.

Comment: This should be marked as answer - it worked for me and a bunch of others

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19042
It is set as CLOSED FIXED, but many users are still reporting the error in the comments area.

A hack is suggested on comment #19:

```
FB.init({
....
....
});
FB.UIServer.setActiveNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._active[a.id]=b;} // IE hack to correct FB bug
```

It worked for some people. I must say it didn't work for me, but I thought it was worth to mention.

Comment: @apaidnerd the fact that this hack works for some and not others suggests that there are different underlying causes for why this error occurs... don't you think?

Comment: Update: Bug 19042 was updated on Facebook Bug Tracker to **STILL NOT FIXED**. So they're aware and hopefully working on it.

Comment: There are two Facebook bugs, [19042](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19042) and [20168](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168).  Both have similar symptoms but different hacks to fix (one fixes setActiveNode, the other fixes setLoadedNode).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this (or a similar problem). Mine was in all.js line 22, char 3160, right after `document.documentElement.style.display='none';` It was a permission denied error.

In my case, it was because the channelUrl was using a different protocol (https) than my app's iframe was being loaded under (http). I tried `//mydomain.com/channel.html`, but that gave me a different error. I solved it by dynamically choosing http/https for channelUrl when generating the html.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Already posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504794/287604, but for the desperate the quick fix:

```
FB.init({
    appId:        'xxxxx',
    appSecret:    'xxxxxxxxx',
    status:        true
    cookie:        true
});

// this code solves the issue
FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) { 
FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still struggling with this but an odd work around I just noticed is if when using fb:login-button when setting the **show-faces** attribute to "true" it suddenly works fine. I tried 2 side by side fb:login buttons and the button with show faces set to either false or not included would pass back the error every time.