# Permission denied error in all.js

Tags: zend-framework, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using all.js for facebook implementation. I used a facebook button on signup page . by logging through facebook i am getting user name and email of facebook user into the fields on sign up page. It's working fine on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but its giving error on IE8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied error in all.js](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7280007/permission-denied-error-in-all-js)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's technological answer to this problem is "channel URL", a window on your domain, through which cross-domain, cross-frame requests can be made.

[Use FB.init and create a channel URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) to overcome this problem. There may be other problems, too, though, IE8 is not generous with error messages. Try investigating in Chrome, what errors are logged in the JavaScript Console.

Best of luck!

Comment: Can u tell me any other tricks actually i did not overcome to this problem .

Comment: Unable to set value of the property 'fbCallID': object is null or undefined all.js, line 22 character 4141

If I trace it down in the script, it comes out this section of code. (Line 22 in all.js) Inside the popup function, this line gets executed.

Comment: Ajay, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280007/permission-denied-error-in-all-js and Facebook bug [19042](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19042) for tips on fixing the fbCallID issue.